# Specify fields for first table in Join

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I was trying to optimize this join since both tables are large (# rows, # records):

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table2 as T2
On T1.X=T2.Y
Set T1.A=T2.B;
```

Ended up getting great performance increase doing:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join (Select T2.Y,T2.B from Table2) as T2
On T1.X=T2.Y
Set T1.A=T2.B;
```

So figured I'd do the same for Table1. Yet when I try:

```
Update (Select T1.X, T1.A from Table1) as T1
Inner Join (Select T2.Y,T2.B from Table2 )as T2
On T1.X=T2.Y
Set T1.A=T2.B;
```

I get the error that T1 is not updateable. How can I know limit the fields loaded by Table1 as well?

Comment: @Dylan Su No in fact it cut the processing time down by 90%

Comment: @Dylan Su Right you are, typo in demo, I fixed, see the edit please.

Comment: I think you can't do the same on T1, since you need to update it. The working query you have is already good enough.

Comment: @DylanSu The problem is it takes far too long. My estimates right now is 44 HOURS which is at least 43 hours too long

Comment: The Update is not possible on a dinamic/temporary table ... for perform the update the table must be a real table .. in you 3th query you use a temporary tbale .. this is the reason of the error ..

Comment: How long does it take for `update Table1 set A='1'`? Maybe it is just because that the table is huge.

Comment: @scaisEdge The update does work it just takes far too long, somewhere around 100 records per second. I need at least 10,000.

Comment: @DylanSu   Simple Update was in fact taking forever, I stopped it. I noticed that field is indexed so removed it, assuming trying to update millions of fields which needed to also index might add overhead, will report back.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see if you have the appropriate index.

Comment: `UPDATEing` all rows of a large table takes a long time, partially because of the "undo" log.